# Why is my express server using prod config, when im indicating it to use dev

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following server startup script for development

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ENV=development nodemon ./bin/www",
    "production": "node ./bin/www",
    "deploy-pre": "git commit --allow-empty -m 'ci-master' && git push origin master",
    "lint": "eslint"
  }
```

The one im using is `npm run start`

I have a folder named ocnfig in root, with a bunch of files

```
config/env --> development.js | index.js | production.js | preproduction.js
```

The template of those files is basically

```
const config = {};

config.dburl = "mongodb://example.com";
config.redisUrl = "example.com";
config.redisPort = 1111;

module.exports = config;
```

And index.js is

```
const production = require("./production");
const preproduction = require("./preproduction");
const development = require("./development");

module.exports = { production, preproduction, development };
```

But then, this only happens with the dbUrl , it uses the production value, even tho im running npm run start, which includes a development flag

To call the value i do

```
    const config = require("../config");

    const notiffConnection = () => {
    mongoose.createConnection(
    config.dburl + "/" + config.notiffDB, { //dburl is coming from production instead of development
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
   }
  )
};
```

Why is this happening?

EDIT: i forgot to add some files

this is index.js , located in config/index.js

```
const env = require("./env");

const currentEnv = process.env.ENV || "production";
console.log("currentenv ", currentEnv) //evaluates to production
module.exports = { ...env["production"], ...env[currentEnv] };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to use the following because of using windows (I had to install cross-env package)

```
"start": "cross-env ENV=development nodemon ./bin/www",
```

instead of

```
"start": "ENV=development nodemon ./bin/www",
```